# ruby constant not getting picked up in other class or tests

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have a Product model with a constant defined on it:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  EMPTY = find_by_name("None Added")

end
```

And then I have a Company model that attempts to make use of the constant:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :product

  before_save :default_values

  def default_values
    self.product ||= Product::EMPTY
  end

end
```

I am using RSpec and FactoryGirl for my tests.

```
describe 'default initialization values' do
    before(:each) do
      create(:product, name: "None Added")
    end

    it 'defaults to the correct product if it is nil' do
      company = create(:company, product: nil)

      expect(company.product).to_not eq(nil)
      expect(company.product.name).to eq("None Added")
    end 
end
```

My test keeps failing because the product remains nil. And when I check the trace it seems my constant Product::EMPTY is returning a nil value. When I drop the constant on a view or in the rails console it gives me the correct value. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `EMPTY = find_by_name("None Added")` is loaded and evaluated when the class is loaded. When you run your specs that means that `find_by_name("None Added")` will find nothing and `EMPTY` will always be nil. That will not change if you create a product named `None Added` later on.

Change your code to something like this to ensure that always an empty product exists:

```
EMPTY = find_or_create_by_name("None Added")
```

Or use a class method instead that is evaluated everytime:

```
def self.empty
  find_by_name("None Added")
end

def default_values
  self.product ||= Product.empty
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You doesn't have `Product` named "None Added" in your test database by the time the constant is set, so `find_by_name("None Added")` returns `nil`. Notice that `EMPTY` constant is set when the `Product` class is evaluated and it's earlier than you create your `'None Added'` product.

Comment: That product named "None Added" is added by this line --> create(:product, name: "None Added") and I checked if it works because in the test I added this code --> expect(Product.find_by_name("None Added").name).to eq("None Added") and it worked.

Comment: @General_9 right but you define your constant before you create this `Product`, like I pointed out in edited answer.